# Problem in Colour in Cerium (IV)Sulphate due to charge transfer

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, color

My text says that $\ce{Ce(SO4)2}$ is coloured due to charge transfer spectra.
It also gives other examples such as $\ce{KMnO_4}$ and $\ce{K_2Cr_2O_7}$, to which I agree but when I read the conditions for charge transfer spectra to take place it says

1. +6;+7;+8 show it more
2. if the central metal atom is diamagnetic but still if compound is showing colour.

I see $\ce{Ce}$ in its +4 oxidation state and configuration
$\ce{[Xe] 4f^1 5d^1 6s^0}$
doesn't show 1st  the conditions then where am I going wrong?

Comment: ohh! no it should have been $Ce(SO_4)_2$ ; But still it doesn't hold the first condition true why?

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34733/why-does-a-mixture-of-siloxene-and-ceriumiv-sulfate-luminesce

Comment: I want to know why both conditions in my text are not true simultaneously?  why?

Comment: Cerium(IV) is not $\ce{[Xe] 4f^1 5d^1 6s^0}$. With $58-4=54$ electrons it must be $\ce{[Xe]}$ only, so diamagnetic and yet colored.